# Conditionally killing a process based on its output

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, shell-script

I have a REPL (read-eval-print-loop) for the [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) programming language listening on a network socket. I can send it code over the network and the code will be evaluated and the answer sent back to me. I'm using the `netcat` utility to send the code

```
# send the contents of code.txt to port 5678 on somemachine
$ netcat somemachine 5678 <code.txt
```

My problem is that I don't want to use the *Loop* capability of this REPL. On my end, I want to issue a one-shot command, receive and show the answer on stdout, then exit my command (the REPL on the remote machine should stay up). The below example works except `netcat` doesn't exit and I remain connected to the REPL indefinitely.

```
$ cat code.txt
(doseq [x (range 0 10)] (println (* x x)))
$ netcat somemachine 5678 <code.txt
user=> 0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
nil
user=>
```

We can see that the REPL's prompt ("user=> ") is displayed twice: once before the code is evaluated and once after. It seems like the key to getting what I want is chaining something on to the end of my command that watches and waits until the prompt is shown a second time then kills `netcat`.

When running this manually in a bash terminal, I could instead just press Ctrl-C after I see the second prompt, but the purpose of this is to be used in an extension to the TextMate editor.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the Clojure-specific case, it looks like you can solve this problem inside out by appending `(.close *in*)` on to the code that is sent to the REPL. (via technomancy on #clojure).

Comment: I don't think `netcat` is the right tool here. You need to send output, then read input until you meet a prompt. This looks like a job for `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other two answers are probably better for your specific case, but to answer your general question, you could tack this bit on the end:

```
netcat somemachine 5678 <code.txt |
    while read ln;do 
      [ "${ln#user=>}" != "$ln" -a "$gotone" = true ] && exit
      [ "${ln#user=>}" != "$ln"  ] && gotone=true
      echo "$ln"
    done
```